# Problems Dual-booting Ubuntu OS on Mac

Tags: boot

How are you supposed to partition the drive on ubuntu so it runs along side the mac os.

Comment: Interesting question, a good answer should be considered for inclusion in http://askubuntu.com/q/343268/40581